# Sign-in with Apple disable "Hide My Email” option

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in

I am getting one problem Sign-in with Apple when user selects  "Hide My Email”.

Can we disable this option ?

Because for important user communication we need actual valid email address.

Comment: The private relay address you get when the user hides their email is an "actual, valid email address"; it is unique and Apple forwards mail to the user, so they will still receive any important user communication.

Comment: @Pradip What did you finally do?

Comment: @Paulw11 you are wrong, user can later turn off proxy and communication is disabled, user will never more receive mail sent by app to proxy mail. We do not accept hidden mail - registration will fail with error message that user must use "share email" not "hide email".

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible.

Users' ability to show/hide their email addresses is related to their preferences and somehow privacy.

See this [link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/132724) for the same question in the Apple forum.

Comment: How does Tinder's "Sign In with Apple" doesn't give option to the user to "Hide my email" instead directly picks up the Apple ID ?

Comment: @OmkarJadhav Tinder doesn't take any requestedScopes i.e`authorizationAppleIDRequest.requestedScopes = []` empty array. Don't pass `.email` or `.fullName` That's why in the next steps it also asks for email. It just maps the account with the user which is a string value received after login.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari yes, your are right. Thanks for explaining this mystery.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't disable that option. But as the link in the previous answer suggests that :-

"If the user chooses to hide their email address from the app, Apple generates a proxy email address to forward email to the user’s private email address".

I would suggest that have a another SignUp Page or Enter Details page which asks for the compulsory things you need like email, mobile number etc.

You can pre-fill the received data from the social accounts. Like if user have already shared the email then have a that data in your signUp page and save in your backend database on click of signup.

Comment: As mentioned Tinder app does not show option to use hidden email. So it means it is possible some how. But question is how?

Comment: @mikep Tinder doesn't take any requestedScopes i.e `authorizationAppleIDRequest.requestedScopes = []` empty array. Don't pass `.email` or `.fullName`. That's why in the next steps it also asks for email. It just maps the account with the user which is a string value received after login.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari yes, your are right. Thanks for explaining this mystery.

Comment: Okay but how do users sign in after that with Apple sign in in case of (Hide my email)?

Comment: @ZiyadMansy It's quite simple. Map your user with a unique id which is actually your user (string) returned from apple credentials. Then provide an option for entering email (sign-up cases only).  For login, whenever you get user (unique string) value from apple, send to your backend and fetch the user who is mapped with this user (string value) from apple creds

Answer (score 0):

As some other answers said it is impossible, I have found a workaround: "hide" from the app that it's an email field. For example for a numeric keyboard, with a phone number, we say:

```
autoComplete="tel"
keyboardType="numeric"
```

That's to improve UX and let users autocomplete without manually imputing the fields. My case was not an exception, so I had and got rid of these fields in my React Native app's `<Input/>` component as passed props:

```
keyboardType="email-address"
autoComplete="email"
```

So it looked something like:

```
<Input
    placeholder="email please"
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCorrect={false}
    autoFocus={true}
    value={email}
    onChangeText={(email) => setEmail(email)}
/>
```

Yet, not sure if it complies with Apple's guidelines.